# How to apply the CSS property 'font-display' globally?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, font-face, webfonts, google-webfonts

I want to make a user style sheet as a Chrome extension, which will override the default [`font-display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display) CSS property with `font-display: swap` for any `@font-face` rule. It should work on any web page, regardless of the way of loading web fonts (`<link rel="stylesheet">`, `@import`, inline `@font-face`). How can I do that?

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: @Makyen Believe me, I know this all, I have already made multiple Chrome extensions. My question is in regard to overriding the `font-display` CSS property in a content script run on any website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use JavaScript in order to enumerate all `@font-face` rules in a content script:

```
[].slice.call(document.styleSheets).forEach(function (sheet) {
    [].slice.call(sheet.cssRules || []).forEach(function (rule) {
        if (rule.type === CSSRule.FONT_FACE_RULE) rule.style.fontDisplay = 'swap';
    });
});
```

Does anybody know the CSS-only way?

Comment: Thank you for writing, I added it as a global userscript and will test to see if it works. I personally hate when websites deny me from viewing their text if webfonts haven't loaded yet. Anyone relying on unchanging font metrics for manually calculated layouts should stop using JS and let the browser do the layout work.